# How can I get EarlGrey to select the keyboard's window or other private UIKit elements?

Tags: ios, ui-automation, earlgrey

I am trying to write a test to automate the showing and hiding of the UI keyboard. However, I need to make sure that the keyboard is visible on the screen whenever I try to make such a call. I found that I can check for an element of the `UIRemoteKeyboardWindow` class to do so, but how do I get `EarlGrey` to match it since there's no direct unique matcher for it. Is there any way with EarlGrey by which you can match on these internal elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/docs/faq.md):

> **How do I create a matcher that matches internal UIKit classes?**
>
> Use NSClassFromString to match on internal classes that can't be
>   referenced directly.
>
> grey_kindOfClass(NSClassFromString("_UIAlertControllerView"))